# How do I sort the values component of an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSDictionary like this:

```
self.channels = @{
                  @"Entertainment" : @[@"SnackableTV", @"Crave", @"Bravo", @"ETVE"],
                  @"Discovery" : @[@"Discovery", @"Discovery Velocity", @"Discovery Investigation", @"Discovery Animal Planet", @"Discovery Science"],
                  @"News" : @[@"CTV", @"CP24", @"BNN", @"CTV News"],
                  @"Sports" : @[@"TSN", @"RDS"],
                  };
self.sortedSectionNames = [[self.channels allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I'm able to sort the section names, but I'm not sure how exactly to sort the values since each value is an array of strings.

Ideally, I want it to come out like this:

```
@"Entertainment": @[@"Bravo", @"Crave", @"ETVE", @"SnackableTV"],
@"Discovery": @[@"Discovery", @"Discovery Animal Planet", @"Discovery Investigation", @"Discovery Science", @"Discovery Velocity"];
```

etc...

I want my table view to have both sorted section headings and sorted rows within each section.  Please advise?

The two variables listed above are defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *> *> *channels;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *sortedSectionNames;
```

Comment: If the arrays are literals why don't you declare them sorted?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to override the setter for the `channels` property:

```
- (void)setChannels:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *> *> *)value {
    NSMutableDictionary *res = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *key in [value allKeys]) {
        NSArray *values = [value[key] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        res[key] = values;
    }

    _channels = [res copy];
}
```

The above was typed into my browser without testing so there could be typos.